# Two FullTextSqlQueries?

Tags: sharepoint

There are two FullTextSqlQueries, one in the namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query
, and the other in Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query. What's the difference between these two? Which one should I use?

Comment: I think you mean `Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query`.

Comment: correct! thanks for finding the mistake. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much difference the way you asked it, but if you meant Microsoft.Office.Server and Microsoft.SharePoint the difference is that one is MOSS and the other is WSS.